# Can Maven Wagon plugin use a private key for scp?

Tags: maven-2, ssh, ssh-keys

Can Maven Wagon plugin be configured to use a private key for ssh/scp? Everything I've tried still leaves maven to ask me for a password when it gets to the point of scp-ing.

Answer (score 18):

You should be able to specify the path to the private key in the [server](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Servers) element in your settings.xml:

> The repositories for download and
>   deployment are defined by the
>   `repositories`  and
>   `distributionManagement`  elements of
>   the POM. However, certain settings
>   such as username  and password should
>   not be distributed along with the
>   pom.xml. This type of information
>   should exist on the build server in
>   the settings.xml.
>
> ```
> <settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
>   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
>                       http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
>   ...
>   <servers>
>     <server>
>       <id>server001</id>
>       <username>my_login</username>
>       <password>my_password</password>
>       <privateKey>${user.home}/.ssh/id_dsa</privateKey>
>       <passphrase>some_passphrase</passphrase>
>       <filePermissions>664</filePermissions>
>       <directoryPermissions>775</directoryPermissions>
>       <configuration></configuration>
>     </server>
>   </servers>
>   ...
> </settings>
> ```
>
> - **id**: This is the ID of the
>     server (not of the user to login as)
>     that matches the id element of the
>     repository/mirror that Maven tries to
>     connect to.
> - **username**, **password**: These elements appear as a pair denoting the login and password
>     required to authenticate to this
>     server.
> - **privateKey**,
>     **passphrase**: Like the previous two elements, this pair specifies a path
>     to a private key (default is
>     `${user.home}/.ssh/id_dsa)` and a
>     passphrase, if required. The
>     passphrase and password elements may
>     be externalized in the future, but for
>     now they must be set plain-text in the
>     settings.xml file.
> - **filePermissions**, **directoryPermissions**: When a repository file or directory is
>     created on deployment, these are the
>     permissions to use. The legal values
>     of each is a three digit number
>     corresponding to *nix file
>     permissions, ie. 664, or 775.
>
> Note: If you use a private key to
>   login to the server, make sure you
>   omit the `<password>` element.
>   Otherwise, the key will be ignored.
>
> **Password Encryption**
>
> A new feature - server password and
>   passphrase encryption has been added
>   to 2.1.x and 3.0 trunks. See details
>   on [this page](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-encryption.html).

Pay a special attention to the "note": *If you use a private key to login to the server, make sure you omit the `<password>` element. Otherwise, the key will be ignored.* So the final configuration will be close to:

```
<settings>
  ...
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>ssh-repository</id>
      <username>your username in the remote system</username>
      <privateKey>/path/to/your/private/key</privateKey>
      <passphrase>sUp3rStr0ngP4s5wOrD</passphrase><!-- if required --> 
      <configuration>
        ...
      </configuration>
    </server>
  </servers>
  ...
</settings>
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old thread, but it looks like the Wagon plugin is reading settings.xml (e.g. username) but not using all of the settings.  I could not get it to stop asking for Kerberos username/password during scp.  (Looks like there might have been changes to plugin late 2016 that affect this.)
Just adding this answer in case it helps someone else.

For me, the solution was even simpler: totally skip using 'settings.xml'
and simply specify 'scpexe' instead of 'scp' for protocol (like under distributionManagement section of pom.xml).  This then uses your machine's default SSH configuration (unix settings under ~/.ssh).

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>wagon-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>upload-to-server</id>
      <phase>deploy</phase>
      <goals><goal>upload-single</goal></goals>
      <configuration>
        <fromFile>file-to-upload</fromfile>
        <url>scpexe://username@serverName/dirname-to-copy-to
        <toFile>file-to-upload</toFile>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Lifesaver answer! Tried private key auth with the `org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-ssh` without success. `org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-ssh-external` worked like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to do the exact same thing today in conjunction with the *maven-site-plugin* (3.9.1) and was also hitting some roadblocks (specifically, the *wagon-ssh* plugin insisted on asking me for my Kerberos username and password).
What finally worked for me with wagon-ssh-**3.4.3**:

```
<!-- add scp support for mvn site:deploy -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
    <artifactId>wagon-ssh</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.3</version>
</dependency>
```

and in ***settings.xml***:

```
<server>
  <id>ssh-repository</id>
  <username>pridkdev</username>
  <privateKey>${user.home}/.ssh/pridkdev.ppk</privateKey>
  <filePermissions>664</filePermissions>
  <directoryPermissions>775</directoryPermissions>
  <configuration>
      <interactive>false</interactive>
      <strictHostKeyChecking>no</strictHostKeyChecking>
      <preferredAuthentications>publickey</preferredAuthentications>
  </configuration>
</server>
```

I guess what was crucial is the `<configuration>` block and there especially the `<preferredAuthentications>` setting.

Answer (score 2):

I found the necessary info here:
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/examples/deploy-ssh-external.html