# Why does Maven not use my privatekey when deploying with scp?

Tags: maven, scp

I am deploying to our cluster using Maven 3. Having set a private-key in my **settings.xml** as well as the repository in the **pom.xml**. At the moment is everything working except that I am getting asked for the password if I call `mvn clean deploy`. If I use `<password>pw</password>` instead of `<privateKey>path</privateKey>` it is working but of course this is not what I want to use.

**settings.xml**

```xml
<server>
    <id>company_cluster</id>
    <username>user</username>
    <privateKey>/home/user/.ssh/user</privateKey>
</server>
```

**pom.xml**

```xml
<build>
    <!-- ... -->
    <extensions>
        <!-- Enabling the use of SSH -->
        <extension>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
            <artifactId>wagon-ssh</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </extension>
    </extensions>

</build>

<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>company_cluster</id>
        <url>scp://client.hadoop.company.at/home/user/deploy/</url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

I have generated a `ssh` key on my local machine and then used

```
ssh-copy-id user@client.hadoop.company.at
```

to add it to the authorized keys.

Comment: there will be some (verbose) log from that, which should tell you why it didn't use your key. Or on server.

Comment: @Jakuje Should I see something if I run it with the `-X` switch? This output is kind of huge and I don't know what I'd look for.

Comment: This should work. Does the path `/home/user/.ssh/user` really point to the private key file (sounds like it should be `id_rsa`)? Do you use a passphrase? Related http://stackoverflow.com/q/2733447/1743880

Comment: @Tunaki I think `id_rsa` is just the name of the file if no other name has been specified. I tried is with `ssh-keygen` and got a `id_rsa` file, tried it but failed as well :/

Comment: Btw: I can login using `ssh` on the server without any troubles so the problem cannot be on the server side.

Comment: @displayname I don't understand. Could you post what is under `/home/user/.ssh` (just the filenames)?

Comment: Also take care about the permissions: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27538847/1743880

Answer (score 1):

It is an old question, but I spend enough time on very similar issue to consider it worth it to post the answer. You cannot give both `username` and `privateKey` in the `server` node in the **settings.xml** file. So in the **settings.xml** file it should be as follows:

```
  <server>
    <id>company_cluster</id>
    <privateKey>/home/user/.ssh/user</privateKey>
  </server>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mvn -U clean install -D skipTests
```

led to the error message:

```
Could not transfer artifact ... from/to ...-repository (scp://.../repo/releases/): Cannot connect. Reason: invalid privatekey: [...-> [Help 1]
```

I found this link https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/Issue-with-key-based-authentication-while-connecting-to-SFTP-server

And checked my newly generated key to be like:

```
-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
...
```

while on my old (working) environment it was:

```
head -2 id_rsa
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
...
```

So the hint from the link above was to use:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -m PEM
```

which would mean to create a new key - i had already deployed the key with ssh-copy-id to quite a few servers already ...

At [Openssh Private Key to RSA Private Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54994641/openssh-private-key-to-rsa-private-key) if found the procedure for the key conversion.

```
ssh-keygen -p -N "" -m pem -f  id_rsa
```

changing the format to RSA

```
head -1 id_rsa
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

and leading to the mvn error message to disappear.